# How do you limit compound records in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, limit

I've been working with MYSQL for a few years now, and I often find myself wondering about this problem, but have never gotten around to researching it until now. So here goes. Let's say I have a table of authors, and a table of books. Each book has a field to link it to an author.

Now let's say I want to get an author and his books, all in one set.

```
SELECT * FROM authors, books WHERE books.author = authors.id
```

No problem so far. Now for the tricky part: how do I get, say, 5 authors AND his books?

if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM authors, books WHERE books.author = authors.id LIMIT 5
```

I'll just wind up getting the first 5 books linked to a single author.

Is that clear enough? Is this possible to do in MYSQL, or do I have to resort to doing it in code (which I don't want to do)?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM authors LIMIT 5) AS authors, books
WHERE books.author = authors.id
```

Read more about subqueries in the FROM clause here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/unnamed-views.html

Comment: Is that the only way? I had hoped there was some more concise method that would involve doing voodoo on the limit clause. The example scenario was very simple, but my actual tables are horrendously complex, and I was hoping for some method that wouldn't involve tearing apart existing query construction. Ah, well. Thanks for the response!